# Fragment partially covered by another fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, fragment

I am opening another fragment (DialogFragment) on top of an existing fragment. The previous fragment is still partially visible. I don't get onPause event on it. Is there any other event we can use when a fragment is pushed into background but remains partially visible?

Both fragments are owned by the same activity. No new activity has been started in my case.

Comment: What do you want to do to the partially visible fragment?

Comment: This question is more important now that google suggests the Single Activity architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Your previous fragment is in background that's why fragment is partially showing. Make Sure two things :
1- your width and height should be "fill_parent" and use background.
2- Use View.setOnClickListner(this); it will disable the previous fragment clicks.